polars: how to find out the number of columns in a polars expression?
I'm building a package on top of Polars, and one of the functions looks like this
def func(x: IntoExpr, y: IntoExpr):
   ...

The business logic requires that x can include multiple columns, but y must be a single column.
What should I do to check and validate this?

You can use the polars.selectors.expand_selector function which lets you evaluate selected columns using either selectors or simple expressions.
Note that the drawback here is that you can’t pass in arbitrary expressions, or else the evaluation fails (see the final examples).
import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs
from polars.selectors import expand_selector

data = {
    "a1": [1, 2, 3],
    "a2": [4, 5, 6],
    "b1": [7, 8, 9],
    "b2": [10, 11, 12],
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

print(
    expand_selector(df, cs.exclude('b1', 'b2')),  # ('a1', 'a2')
    expand_selector(df, cs.starts_with('b')),     # ('b1', 'b2')
    expand_selector(df, cs.matches('(a|b)1$')),   # ('a1', 'b1')

    # use with expressions expand_selector(..., strict=False)
    expand_selector(df, pl.exclude('a1', 'a2'), strict=False), # ('b1', 'b2')
    expand_selector(df, pl.col('b1'),           strict=False), # ('b1', )
    expand_selector(df, pl.all(),               strict=False), # ('a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2')
    sep='\n'
)

# anything past an arbitrary selection expression will fail
print(expand_selector(df, pl.all() + 1, strict=False))

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "/home/cameron/.vim-excerpt", line 26, in <module>
#     expand_selector(df, pl.all() + 1, strict=False),
#   File "/home/cameron/.pyenv/versions/dutc-site/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/selectors.py", line 190, in expand_selector
#     raise TypeError(msg)
# TypeError: expected a selector; found <Expr ['[(*) + (dyn int: 1)]'] at 0x7F835F943D30> instead.


Hi Cameron, thanks for this. expand_selector was something I was testing. I though it doesn't take regular expressions!

At the very least, you can support regular expression with polars.selectors.matches. For your interface, you may want to constrain your users to passing in explicit selectors instead of expressions? (I updated my answer to include an example using selectors.matches)

There are introspection methods in the Meta namespace, e.g.

has_multiple_outputs()

>>> pl.col(["a", "b"]).meta.has_multiple_outputs()
True

>>> pl.col("a").meta.has_multiple_outputs()
False


Hi jqurious, thanks for the input! This certainly works when I specifically input more than two columns in pl.col(). Things become less clear when I have to deal with pl.exclude("a") (surprise!, I only have two columns, so pl.Exclude actually is just one column; or polars selectors (which will never tell me the correct info without seeing the dataframe)!

Ah - yes, that's a bit different alright. I'm not sure how you would go about that with just expressions. pl.concat_list(pl.exclude("a")).list.len().first() != 1 comes to mind - but that's not really something you can check without running. And is probably an expensive operation.

Hi jqurious, the answer Cameron posted seems to be robust. Let me know if you have other thoughts!

@MarkWang Yes - it is, but expand_selector() needs the df. If you have the df, you can just run whatever expressions and check what columns are returned. e.g. df.select(pl.exclude("a")).columns

I guess the main diff is that I don't want to waste resources to materialise the result, with expand_selector(), I can simply use the schema: expand_selector(df.schema, cs.numeric())

Yeah, it probably just creates an empty frame before running pl.DataFrame(schema=df.schema).select(...) - I haven't checked.
